# Image grid not lining up

Tags: css, image, alignment

The left and right edges of the images on the second row do not line up with the row above. They are only out by a few pixels it seems.

The main large image at the bottom does not line up with the row above.

[Link to site](http://www.tigzcreative.co.uk/2016/11/20/is-this-it/)

Comment: [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Not any help on this site

Comment: Provide a [*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just a link to your site. Include the relevant HTML and CSS in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add ever image in your gallery list 'width 100%':

```
img { width: 100% }
```

and remove 'text-align: center' in

```
<div id="production-photo-gallery"> and <ul>
```

then add padding to first `<li>` in `<ul id='main-production-image'>`

```
#main-production-image > li { padding-right: 2%; }
```